# Error con json en jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

En mi página hago dos llamadas a json de la misma API pero distintos recursos:

```
function buscaInvocador($nombre) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/$nombre?api_key=RGAPI-de016c14-78f2-4e19-82a7-33526d8bed4c",
        dataType: "json",
    }).done(function() {
        $('.idInvocador').append("Hola");
    }).fail(function() {
        $('.idInvocador').append("Adios");
    })
}
```

Esta url no funciona, siempre entra en el `.fail` pero estoy seguro de que me devuelve el JSON *(la url en el navegador funciona y se ve como devuelve el json)*.

> {"id":97938335,"accountId":232092599,"name":"Ka0x14","profileIconId":1627,"revisionDate":1491345737000,"summonerLevel":12}

Por otro lado, esta llamada a url si funciona correctamente. jquery me detecta el json y puedo jugar con el.

La llamada siempre entra en el `.done`

```
function buscaMaestria($id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://euw.api.riotgames.com/api/lol/EUW/v1.4/summoner/$id/masteries?api_key=RGAPI-de016c14-78f2-4e19-82a7-33526d8bed4c",
        dataType: "json",
    }).done(function() {
        $('.idInvocador').append("Hola");
    }).fail(function() {
        $('.idInvocador').append("Adios");
    })
}
```

El json resultante es el siguiente.

```
{"23385178":{"summonerId":23385178,"pages":[{"id":34451272,"name":"Thresh","current":false,"masteries":[{"id":6342,"rank":1},{"id":6241,"rank":1},{"id":6311,"rank":5},{"id":6221,"rank":1},{"id":6211,"rank":5},{"id":6322,"rank":1},{"id":6332,"rank":5},{"id":6232,"rank":5},{"id":6362,"rank":1},{"id":6352,"rank":5}]},{"id":34451273,"name":"Alistar","current":false,"masteries":[{"id":6342,"rank":1},{"id":6311,"rank":5},{"id":6241,"rank":1},{"id":6221,"rank":1},{"id":6211,"rank":5},{"id":6322,"rank":1},{"id":6332,"rank":5},{"id":6231,"rank":5},{"id":6352,"rank":5},{"id":6362,"rank":1}]},{"id":34451274,"name":"Tahm","current":false,"masteries":[{"id":6342,"rank":1},{"id":6223,"rank":1},{"id":6311,"rank":5},{"id":6241,"rank":1},{"id":6211,"rank":5},{"id":6263,"rank":1},{"id":6322,"rank":1},{"id":6332,"rank":5},{"id":6232,"rank":5},{"id":6252,"rank":5}]},{"id":34451275,"name":"Karma","current":false,"masteries":[{"id":6223,"rank":1},{"id":6342,"rank":1},{"id":6241,"rank":1},{"id":6311,"rank":5},{"id":6322,"rank":1},{"id":6332,"rank":5},{"id":6212,"rank":5},{"id":6231,"rank":5},{"id":6363,"rank":1},{"id":6352,"rank":5}]},{"id":34451276,"name":"Bardo","current":false,"masteries":[{"id":6223,"rank":1},{"id":6342,"rank":1},{"id":6241,"rank":1},{"id":6311,"rank":5},{"id":6331,"rank":5},{"id":6211,"rank":5},{"id":6322,"rank":1},{"id":6351,"rank":5},{"id":6232,"rank":5},{"id":6362,"rank":1}]},{"id":34451279,"name":"Pág. de maestrías 8","current":false,"masteries":[{"id":6121,"rank":1},{"id":6343,"rank":1},{"id":6111,"rank":5},{"id":6321,"rank":1},{"id":6331,"rank":5},{"id":6142,"rank":1},{"id":6312,"rank":5},{"id":6162,"rank":1},{"id":6134,"rank":5},{"id":6151,"rank":5}]},{"id":34451280,"name":"Mastery Page 9","current":false,"masteries":[{"id":6223,"rank":1},{"id":6342,"rank":1},{"id":6241,"rank":1},{"id":6311,"rank":5},{"id":6211,"rank":5},{"id":6322,"rank":1},{"id":6332,"rank":5},{"id":6231,"rank":5},{"id":6363,"rank":1},{"id":6352,"rank":5}]},{"id":34451281,"name":"Ivern","current":true,"masteries":[{"id":6343,"rank":1},{"id":6114,"rank":5},{"id":6134,"rank":4},{"id":6122,"rank":1},{"id":6331,"rank":5},{"id":6312,"rank":5},{"id":6322,"rank":1},{"id":6143,"rank":1},{"id":6351,"rank":5},{"id":6131,"rank":1},{"id":6362,"rank":1}]}]}}
```

Ambas funciones son exactamente iguales, lo único que varía es la url del recurso de la api. Los json resultantes tienen formato distinto y quizás tenga que especificar en el data de mi función el formato del json, pero no tengo mucha idea de esto.

---

La variable `$nombre` la pongo para que sepamos que ahí va un valor variable. Las pruebas las hago con "*`Ka0x14`*". En el navegador el json me lo devuelve, pero la función me falla.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo - es porque no le has puesto un nombre a la variable $nombre ... si lo cambias por ejemplo por `dani` te sale un json válido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que el error podria ser que no estas concatenando correctamente la variable que recibes por parametro  seria algo asi:

```
function buscaInvocador($nombre){
$.ajax({
    url: "https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/"+$nombre+"?api_key=RGAPI-de016c14-78f2-4e19-82a7-33526d8bed4c",
    dataType: "json",
}).done(function(){
    $('.idInvocador').append("Hola");
}).fail(function(){
    $('.idInvocador').append("Adios");
})
```

Comment: Lo de la variable lo he puesto aqui para que veamos que ese valor es variable, pero las pruebas las estoy haciendo con un nombre directamente.